# What does "% of Queue" refer to in the hadoop yarn UI

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, hadoop-yarn

I regularly schedule spark applications via yarn and use the yarn web UI in order to track the applications. However, I haven't been able to figure out what this column in the applications table refers to:

[image: % of Queue column in yarn ui]

I can't find any information about it online. Does anyone know what "% of Queue" means in this context?

Comment: I reckon this column indicates the sum of the capacities for all the queues you have scheduled expressed in percentages of 100. 

You might be baffled about the >100% values at the top two scheduled spark application of the screenshot, but I think it might be this way because your infrastructure supports elasticity, so the applications are using more resources when it's needed from the pool of the free resources that are used when it's needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thats "the percentage of resources of the queue that the app is using" [[source]](https://github.com/apache/hadoop/blob/1002c582d86ae8689c497c3d31b73f1ab92d5e29/hadoop-yarn-project/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-api/src/main/java/org/apache/hadoop/yarn/api/records/ApplicationResourceUsageReport.java#L161).

%-age over a hundred can occur, for example, if you're using FairScheduler, due to the difference in queue's Instantaneous vs Steady fair share.